# SQL Query to Count Answers

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here's my dilemma. I'm working on a database that will take a student's answer sheet, put in table [Answers] and compare it to an answer key in table [Tests]. Also, associated with each question is a specific education standard.

I get an excel export from our testing website for the answer sheets.  It's setup as follows:

`| Student ID | Student | Ans 1 | Ans 2 | Ans 3 | etc... |`

So [Answers] is setup to be a simple direct import from Excel.

The end result wanted is a counted list of standards that the student missed.  I.E.:

```
| Name     | Standard | Count |
| John Doe | ABC1234  |   8   |
```

I'm at a loss on how to get to that point.  I can get the standards missed, but then I can't count horizontally.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to need to *unpivot* the data from the table using a `UNION ALL` query:

```
select [student id], [student], [Ans 1] As Answer
from yourtable
union all
select [student id], [student], [Ans 2] As Answer
from yourtable
union all
select [student id], [student], [Ans 3] As Answer
from yourtable
union all
select [student id], [student], [Ans 4] As Answer
from yourtable
```

Once the data is in one column, then you will be able to apply `count()`